# nokogiri multiple css classes

Tags: html, css, xpath, parsing, nokogiri

How is it possible to select an html element that have two classes?

For example, how to select the element `<p>` bellow in an HTML document (given that it has two css classes) `class='class1 class2'`.

I tried to use the following:

- `doc.xpath("//p[@class~='class1 class2']")`
- `doc.xpath("//p[@class~='class1']|[@class~='class2']")`
- `doc.xpath("//p[@class~='class1',@class~='class2']")`
- `doc.xpath("//p[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' class1 ') &&   contains(concat(' ',@class, ' '), ' class2 ')]")`

but without success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `//p[@class~='class1'][@class~='class2']`, maybe.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally I found the RIGHT way to search multiple css classes with nokogiri (libxml) :

```
doc.xpath('//p[contains(@class, "class1") and contains(@class, "class2")]')
```

It's not perfect, because if `<p>` contains classes such as `class10` and `class20` the element will be selected, but for now it's enough for what I need. If you have more suggestions they are welcome!

#### Update

Here is a better solution to this problem using css only :

```
doc.css('p.class1.class2')
```

Thanks to Aaron Patterson :-)

Comment: Just for others, when a class has just numbers (.2011), the .css selector doesn't work. .2011 is a valid class when parsing as css, you just have to do .\32 011 {} when defining the style.